# Export Magento Data to 1.7 from 1.3

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a unique issue that I haven't been able to grasp yet.  I have upgraded a Magento site from 1.3.2.4 via command line on a test site to 1.7.0.2.  The problem is, when I perform this update, it deletes all data when creating/deleting the tables/columns/rows --  So I end up with the correct structure and schema I just don't have any of my data.  I performed the following:

`./pear mage-setup`

`./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable`

`chmod 550 ./mage`

`./mage mage-setup`

This got me updated to 1.4.2.0    Next I performed the following"

`./mage sync`

`./mage list-upgrades`

`./mage config-set preferred_state stable`

`./mage upgrade-all --force`

These all succeeded, and when I go to the mage store it reads 1.7.0.2.  Just non of my products, customers or categories are in the DB.  It's intact, and if I create new from there, it works, however I looked at the structure and it's, for the most part, different.  Has anyone out there written a script, or a series of MySQL calls to align these databases?  You'd think I could export a CSV and then import, and Magento would have a contingency for this...  But no they don't.  And their answer when contacted?  Move to the $15,000 Enterprise addition for support ..  LMAO  Whatever ...

In short I need to migrate one database to another, or I am going to have to manually input 2500 products and 50000 customers.  Not good lol. Ideas, experience, scripts?

Comment: First, that popped in my mind is doing reindex and clearing the cache, but may be you already tried this? I always do the upgrades in small steps and never use automatic scripts. While doing the upgrade I  check what is the condition of the store. So for example I upgrade 1.4.1.1 -> 1.4.2.0 -> 1.5.0.1 ...

Comment: @ceckoslab ... Thanks for your comment, though I have re-indexed and cleared/disabled all caches.  I am working on building an export script to do this for me, but it takes a pretty in depth understanding of both schemas, and they are quite different.

Comment: May be you need some professional help ... check this if you can't find the answer here: http://www.mageupdate.com/splash/

Comment: I AM a professional ... but, thanks.  I was looking for a simpler way to get it done.  No sense in reinventing the wheel if at all possible.  I CAN do it, just was wondering if anyone else already had.

Comment: Hey @Zak :) It looks like you are professional! Let us know, how you when you resolve this problem! And just in case if you need some help feel free to contact me ...

Comment: I am building a custom shell script that I will run command line.  I am going through the database, table by table, and logging the differences.  Next I will do things like add an attribute to 1.7 that is identical to a 1.3 attribute, and log database changes, compare and add to the script to pull the data from 1.3, alter it to the structure of 1.7 and insert the newly altered data into tables accordingly.  I have tested the theory by adding a simple product with no categories or attributes to the 1.3 and using the method above transferred it over to the 1.7 flawlessly.

Comment: @Zak did you get any further with this, I am currently working on a 1.3 upgrade to 1.9.1